# Multiple Webparts with OOTB connections or CEWP with HTML and JS with multiple REST calls.Which is better in performance

Tags: rest, performance, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a page with around 12 ListView Webparts.There is one Master ListView Webpart which provides filter connections to the other webparts, so that it displays the filtered results.
Keeping in mind for performance and to use best approach should this approach be continued or should i create a single content editor webpart and use multiple REST calls to achieve the same, or is there any other better approach.

Please Suggest.Also if any features i can consider in SP 2016

Comment: Have you considered using custom result sources and display templates / filtering templates. I would think it would be much faster and more efficient than multiple web parts or Rest calls. https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC322

Comment: As less REST calls as possible, they can take from 100ms to over 2 seconds (worst cases I've seen in production) to return your data (see your F12 Network tab) Analyse where you current performance problem is, It could well be, setting indexes on List Fields boosts performance

Comment: This is a very open ended question. Not sure all that's involved. Depends on the types of lists, how many results you are returning, etc. First of all, you have to think, what is your end goal? If it's just one filter, I would use a Content Query webpart with custom result sources like @Col.Cook mentioned or use SharePoint Designer to achieve that. OOTB is going to work better in my opinion than multiple REST calls.

Comment: @Col.Cook i was also thinking to use search based solution, but my concern is the latency in the results coming up. The system always needs to be displaying the most recent and updated results.Even if i go for a continuous crawl i guess there would still be a delay of 1-2 min in the results coming up.

Comment: Yes there will be a delay, if you are On-Prem you can reduce the delay by setting up an isolated content source and even devote extra resources if its that important to keep it as up to date as possible.